# PyCharm/WebStorm/IntelliJ syntax highlighting individual keywords

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm

PyCharm is my goto IDE and praise it for it's customization. While I was tweaking the color of keywords is it possible to configure different colors for different keywords?

Specifically when I want to work in NodeJS I want to color `for`, `if`, `return` in different color and other keywords like `let`, `var`, `async`, `const` in different color.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible in current versions: all those keywords will be highlighted as per what Color Scheme allows (those categories only).

For custom highlighting, watch after https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5473 and maybe related tickets as well (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: Thanks for the good directions. Seems one of the developers has got it somewhat close https://github.com/mallowigi/Custom-Syntax-Highlighter